# how to get surface direction of object in hit point in unity

Tags: unity

I'm simulating shooting by raycasting. I want to instantiate a bullet hole or mark on the spot where a bullet hits an object. But the surface of the object at that point may have different angle or direction:

[image: example]

How can I find the object's surface direction to make the right transform for a bullet hole?

Comment: This is a short answer: [RaycastHit.normal](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-normal.html)

Comment: Yeah it's simple Raycasthit.normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direction a polygon is facing is called its "normal". Thus, you want to get the normal at the spot hit. Raycasts return that information: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-normal.html